# How can I check if a YouTube channel name exists?

Tags: php, javascript, web, youtube, youtube-api

I own a website that generates YouTube names, how can I show the user if a channel is already taken or not?

Comment: Use YouTube API at server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$api = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/';
$user = "user";
$headers = get_headers($api . $user, true);
if ($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK") {
    // its ok
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [channel->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) request for this.

As mentioned in [documents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids), all you need to do is do

```
channels.list(part="id", forUsername="username")
```

If this return an empty list, there is no channel with that username.

Also [here are some samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples) to get you started.